# Fire Laravel events on touch

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5

this is my scenario:
I'm using Laravel 5.5.x.
I have two models, linked in one to many way.

```
class Artwork extends Model
{
   //It has timestamps
   protected $table = 'artworks';
   protected $fillable = [
        'artwork_category_id'
   ];
   public function artworkCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ArtworkCategory');
    }
}

class ArtworkCategory extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $touches = ["artworks"];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'artwork_categories';
     protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
        'acronym',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function artworks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Artwork');
    }
}
```

Touch works correctly, so when I update an artwork category the related artworks updated_at field is updated.

But I need to listen the "touch" event on each artwork.
I've tried inserting "updated" listener on boot method in AppServiceProvider, but it is not fired.

```
Artwork::updated(function ($model){
            \Log::debug("HERE I AM");
        });
```

I've tried using an observer, but no luck.

```
class ArtworkObserver
{
    public function updated(Artwork $artwork)
    {
        dd($artwork);
    }
}
```

Boot method in AppServiceProvider:

```
Artwork::observe(ArtworkObserver::class)
```

**Question:**
Could somebody show me the right way to do it? Or tell me where am I wrong?
I was not good enough to find an example that helps me how to do it.

**Update**
I need to achieve this because I have to "fire" Scout to save updated data on Elasticsearch on Artwork index.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by listening `Artwork` touches? `$touches` will not fire those events for the `Artwork` models, because models are never created rather mass updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably `$touches` uses **mass update**, and if you check [`Events`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events) section of `Eloquent` you'll find following:

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the `saved` and `updated` model events will **not be fired** for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

---

The best that I can think of is that, you update `Artwork`s manually (instead of `$touches`) when a `ArtworkCategory` is updated:

```
class ArtworkCategory extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

     protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
        'acronym',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function artworks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Artwork');
    }

    public static function boot()
   {
       parent::boot();

       static::updated(function($artworkCategory)
       {
            $artworkCategory->artworks->each(function($artwork) {
                $artwork->setUpdatedAt($artwork->freshTimestamp());
                $artwork->save(); /// Will trigger updated on the artwork model
            });
       });       
   }    
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Do you know if is there another way to achieve that? (I've updated the question)

Comment: Thank you Orkhan, I've based my solution on your code. A little tip if you need to trigger updated starting by multiple models: if you inherit your models from a custom class that inherits from Model, you can write your boot method there and check if the currently used model has a relation with the entity you want to update.